# Python, Price Checker with Requests not running

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a price checker with requests and beautifulsoup, I'm using customtkinter for the GUI and openpyxl for saving the date and price in an excel sheet.

the error is that when I run the file it doesn't start and the GUI doesn't come up, i have done some error handling and i have found out that the code freezes in line 80 (htmlpage = requests.get(URL)).
Therefor i have concluded that the error is in the requests library.

if someone could help me fix this it would be great, also if you find any other errors in the code please comment it and feel free to give me suggestions about how to make the code better.

python 3.10

code:

```
from customtkinter import *
import openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import requests


root = CTk()
root.title("Price Checker App")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Axelr/PycharmProjects/PC01/main/Self built/Price checker/icon.ico")
root.geometry("550x300")

set_appearance_mode("dark")
set_default_color_theme("green")

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="price_data.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

URL = "https://www.komplett.no/product/1217710/mobiler-klokker/mobiltelefoner/iphone-14-128gb-blaa"


def view_history():
    hroot = CTk()
    hroot.title("Price Checker App")
    hroot.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Axelr/PycharmProjects/PC01/main/Self built/Price checker/icon.ico")
    hroot.geometry("700x500")

    set_appearance_mode("dark")
    set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

    def load_data():
        row = sheet.max_row

        date_list = []
        price_list = []

        for _ in range(row):
            date = (sheet.cell(row, 1).value)
            price = (sheet.cell(row, 2).value)
            if date is None:
                break
            date_list.append(date)
            price_list.append(price)
            row += 1


        counter = 0
        for _ in range(len(date_list)):
            date_price = f"{date_list[counter]}: {price_list[counter]} Kr"
            CTkLabel(master=hroot, text=date_price, text_font=("Roboto", 18)).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
            counter += 1



    def delete_data():
        row = sheet.max_row

        for _ in range(row):
            if row == 1:
                break
            sheet[f"A{row}"] = None
            sheet[f"B{row}"] = None
            row -= 1
        workbook.save(filename="price_data.xlsx")

        print("All data deleted!")

    load_data()

    delete_btn = CTkButton(master=hroot, text="Delete All Data", text_font=("Roboto", 20), command=delete_data)
    delete_btn.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    hroot.mainloop()

def get_price():
    placement = sheet.max_row + 1
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_datetime = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    htmlpage = requests.get(URL)
    content = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.content, "html.parser")

    results = content.find(id="MainContent")
    print(results)

    if False:
        row_to_check = sheet.max_row
        latest_date_saved = (sheet.cell(row_to_check, 1).value)
        if latest_date_saved != current_datetime:
            sheet[f"A{placement}"] = current_datetime
            sheet[f"B{placement}"] = price
            workbook.save(filename="price_data.xlsx")
            print("Data Saved!")
        else:
            print("Data Already Saved!")


get_price()

#GUI

title_label = CTkLabel(master=root, text="Price Checker", text_font=("Roboto", 24))
title_label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

price_label = CTkLabel(master=root, text="Price: ", text_font=("Roboto", 24))
price_label.pack(padx=20, pady=30)

history_btn = CTkButton(master=root, text="Open History", text_font=("Roboto", 24), command=view_history)
history_btn.pack(padx=20, pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have found out that the code freezes in line 80 (htmlpage =
> requests.get(URL)). Therefor i have concluded that the error is in the
> requests library.

Default behavior of `requests.get` is to have +infinity timeout, therefore you might observe freeze if server does not provide response in reasonable time. [`timeout`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts) keyword argument might be used to provoke error in such situation, e.g.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.example.com",timeout=10)
```

gives 10 seconds. It is advisable for production code to use that parameter

> Nearly all production code should use this parameter in nearly all
> requests. Failure to do so can cause your program to hang indefinitely

Comment: thanks for the answer, but do you have an answer to make the data load?